# How to count the words in a column and group them together in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am struggling to find a way to split the words within a column in a column into multiple rows and count the occurrences.

Looking for some advice on possible ways to achieve requirement.

Table:

[image]

Internally I wanted to split the words into multiple rows:

[image]

Then finally group them to count the duplicates:

[image]

Comment: _Internally I wanted to split the words into multiple rows:_ You already know how to do that - one of your previous questions involves that very task.

Comment: I couldn't find any previous Qs that relates to transforming one row to multiple rows @SMor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2016 or later, we can take advantage of `STRING_SPLIT` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT value AS A
    FROM yourTable
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(ColumnA, ',')
)

SELECT A, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM cte
GROUP BY A;
```

### Demo